# What functions can be used to dilate a probability distribution function?

Tags: geometry, statistics, functions

Convolving any distribution $p(x)$ by a $\delta(t-\tau)$ will horizontally shift the distribution by $\tau$. What mathematical operation can I perform on $p(x)$ that will horizontally dilate it (i.e., I want to generate some function $g(x)$ where $g(3x)=p(x)$). In my specific case, I'm working with probability distribution functions that I want to horizontally dilate by some constant.

New here, so please let me know if I should've asked the above question in a different way! Thanks!

Edit: 
I mean probability density. To be more clear, I'm looking for a function that can be applied to p(x) directly instead of through substitution (i.e., $p(x) ?h(x)=g(x))$, where ? is some operator and $h(x)$ is some function/distribution. In the shifting example above, the delta function would be h(x).

Comment: Is $p(x)$ a probability density or a cumulative distribution function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you meant probability density.

You know that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)dx=1.
$$
Using the substitution rule with $x=3y$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}3p(3y)dy=1.
$$
So your "dilated" probability density is $y\mapsto3p(3y)$.

Comment: Yes, I mean probability density. To be more clear, I'm looking for a function that can be applied to p(x) directly instead of through substitution (i.e., $p(x) ?h(x)=g(x))$, where ? is some operator and $h(x)$ is some function/distribution. In the shifting example above, the delta function would be h(x).

Comment: Technically, $G$ defined by $(Gp)(y) = 3p(3y)$ is an operator... ;-)

Comment: You should narrow down your problem though, as it stands, it's too broad. Maybe pick a specific operator (e.g., multiplication).

Comment: Hmm I see. I've been thinking about mostly convolution or multiplication. In your example above you still don't derive an h(x) for $p(x)?h(x)=g(x)$. I'd like a form where I have both an operator (multiplication or convolution, ideally) and a function that does the transformation h(x).